# Successful Intervlan Routing on a Layer 3 Switch, Unsuccessful IP Routing

Tags: routing, vlan, layer3

Hello and thank you in advance for your help!

I'm using Packet Tracer for testing purposes and I' m trying to implement a simple intervlan routing in a Layer 3 Switch (3560-24PS) and an IP Routing.

The problem is that intervlan routing is successfull but the simple IP routing is unsuccessful.

My topology is the following:

[image] 
**PC0**: IP: 192.168.2.50 / Mask: 255.255.255.0 / Gateway: 192.168.2.1

**PC1**: IP: 192.168.3.50 / Mask: 255.255.255.0 / Gateway: 192.168.3.1

**Switch0, Switch1**: I have created vlans 2 and 3, Fa0/1 ports have been configured as Trunk ports, Fa0/2 ports have been configured as Access ports in the corresponding vlan.

**Router0**: Fa0/0 has been configured with the IP 10.10.10.1/24 and is enabled.

Now, I am presenting the configuration of the **Layer 3 Switch**:

[image]

Additionally, I' m presenting the output of the *show ip route* command.

[image]

As a result:

I **can** ping PC1 from PC0.

I **can** ping PC0 from PC1.

I **can** ping default gateways from PC0 and PC1.

I **can** ping 10.10.10.2 from PC0 and PC1.

I **can** ping 10.10.10.1 for Multilayer switch.

But, I **cannot** ping 10.10.10.1 from PC0 and PC1.

Could you help me? Why is the IP routing unsuccessful? I cannot find a solution here...

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please, never use an image for text in your post. Simply copy the text, ten paste it into your post, then use the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`) to get the proper formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, Router 0 does not have a route to 192.168.2.0 or 192.168.3.0.  You need to add static route for these networks with the switch as the next hop (10.20.10.2).

Comment: Yes, you' re right!! I thought that the routes on the Layer 3 Switch would be sufficient, but I should have configured the routes on the Router, too. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

As per configuration when ping 10.10.10.1 from PC0 route need to configure in layer3 pointing towards router interfàce

**Ensure below route entries are configured**

`Multi layer switch(config)#ip route 10.10.10.0255.255.255.255 10.10.10 .1`

`Router(config)# ip route 192.168.2.0. 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.2`